# How to turn on and off a lot of jQuery click activated functions and then have them turn on again

Tags: jquery, bind, unbind

I have two buttons on my site which act as a toggle to allow an **'include'** or **'exclude'** mode to take place. The include button is highlighted by default.

This is the HTML for the two buttons:

```
<div class="smallmenu women abs on" id="include"><div class="text">include</div></div>
<div class="smallmenu men abs hov" id="exclude"><div class="text">exclude</div></div>
```

Include is activated by default (hence the 'on' class). When a button is 'on' I don't want people to be able to hover on it and see an effect (this is why include does not have the 'hov' class and exclude does) and I don't want clicking it to do anything. To switch mode I want people to have to click the other button.

I am able to make the effects I want take place with **jQuery** when someone clicks the 'exclude' button, and I am able to make that button stop being active once it has been clicked (with `$("#exclude").unbind();` ), but when someone then clicks the **'include'** button I don't know how to make the **'exclude'** button become active again.

I also don't know how to prevent the **'include'** button from being active when the page first loads. But I haven't really played with this part yet.

Here is some code:

```
$("#exclude").click(function() {
    $(this).toggleClass("on");
    $(".filtercategory").toggleClass("inc");
    $("#include").toggleClass("on");
    $("#include").toggleClass("hov");
    $(this).toggleClass("hov");
    $("#alternatefilterinfo").toggleClass("hide");
    $("#defaultfilterinfo").toggleClass("hide");
    $("#exclude").unbind();
        }); 


$("#include").click(function() {
    $(this).toggleClass("on");
    $(".filtercategory").toggleClass("inc");
    $("#exclude").toggleClass("on");
    $("#exclude").toggleClass("hov");
    $(this).toggleClass("hov");
    $("#exclude").bind(); //this line fails to do anything!
})
```

Answer (score 1):

The `.bind()` function doesn't have a "memory" of the handler(s) that were previously removed. As explained in [the `.bind()` documentation](http://api.jquery.com/bind) you have to pass it a function the same way you pass one to `.click()`.

Rather than trying to unbind and then re-bind, how about this:

```
$("#exclude").click(function() {
   if ($(this).hasClass("on")) {
       return;
   }
   // your other code here
});
```

...and similar for the other button. That is, when the control is clicked check if it is already "on" and if so do nothing (i.e., return immediately).

Answer (score 1):

If you want a `global` switch to turn events on/off, there isn't one. But you can 'mock' one by having a global variable that is checked within the function of the triggered event.

For example:

```
var eventsSwitchedOn = true; //global switch

$("#mybutton").click(function() {
    if(eventsSwitchedOn) { alert("I am allowed to fire a click event!"); }
});

//now you can test it like this:

eventsSwitchedOn = false;

$("#mybutton").click(); //will do nothing

eventsSwitchedOn = true;

$("#mybutton").click(); //will alert the message
```